# Apache Poi 3.13 can't find classes to open XLSX files

Tags: java, excel, maven, apache-poi

I am using apache POI to read and write Excels' files with Java, but I am not able to find **WorkbookFactory** nor **XSSFWorkbook** in the sources to read xlsx files.

**pom.xml** :

```
<poi.version>3.13</poi.version>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>${poi.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>${poi.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I can't find neither any information in the changelog of apache poi that could lead to this behaviour.

**Edit**:
Here my implementation (just a simple method for the moment)

```
public static HSSFSheet getXLSSheet(String fileName, int sheetIndex) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    return workbook.getSheetAt(sheetIndex);
}
```

I tried to open an XLSX file but since I can't find the two other classes (WorkbookFactory or XSSFWorkbook) I was expected to have an error like this one:

```
org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First up, I can assure you that the `WorkbookFactory` and `XSSFWorkbook` classes are contained in the POI-OOXML 3.13 jars, as [documented on the POI site](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components)

```
$ unzip -l .m2/repository/org/apache/poi/poi-ooxml/3.13/poi-ooxml-3.13.jar | grep WorkbookFactory
  6041  2015-09-22 00:22   org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.class
```

However, as the exception you have posted makes clear, your code will never work for `XLSX` files, it needs changing. Well, for that and some other issues too... eg [Don't use an InputStream if you have a File](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream)

Your code should instead be more like:

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

public static Sheet getExcelSheet(String fileName, int sheetIndex) throws IOException {
   File file = new File(fileName);
   Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
   return workbook.getSheetAt(sheetIndex);
}
```

That will work for both `xls` and `xlsx` files, and will be lower memory than using an input stream. As long as you tell maven to depend on the `poi-ooxml` jar, you'll get all the other dependencies you need automatically

Comment: I knew it that it wasn't going to work. But thank you to find out that it is in the 3.13 version. I found out that there was an error with the IDE, for some how the dependency wasn't loaded. Now everything is working fine. I also changed to the File instead of InputStream (but for the testing purpose I tried the fastest way)

Answer (score 0):

The XSSFWorkbook presents in 3.11 version of Apache POI.

[Source code of apache POI](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/branches/REL_3_11_BRANCH/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/)

Try to use this version of apache poi.

Also, it still present in trunk:

[Source code of apache POI](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/)

I believe the issue is with you maven local storage. try to remove poi folederes from maven local repository and redownload dependencies.

Also try to not forget to change all call from `HSSFWorkbook` to `XSSFWorkbook`, because **XLSX** files opens via `XSSFWorkbook` only.